# If the "we" refers to a company, is it "is" or "are"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subject-verb-agreement

Example

> MicroLoft is a software company based in Los Angeles. We offer software development and maintenance services and ***is*** one of the few software companies with full Lookle certified team.

Should it be "are" instead of "is"?

Comment: Certainly it should be. You can't say _we is_ in correct English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the company is using 'we' to refer to *themselves* as the members of that organisation, then it should be "*we are*".

Companies are usually referred to in the singular form (eg '*Microsoft Corporation **is** an American multinational technology corporation*') as they are single entities, but spokespersons for companies often use '*we are*' in communications, as in your example, when they are talking about the work or values of the many people employed. So you could see "we are", "they are", or "it is" used in connection with the same company depending on who is speaking and the perspective.

Comment: Companies, teams, government departments, etc, are very often referred to in the plural in UK usage.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I wouldn't say "very often" - it's completely contextual. I just went on BBC News and the most recent article about a company - BP - refers to "**its** profits" (not 'their' profits).

Comment: Yes. The same [UK government document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/821324/Pack_A_-_English_-_Web.pdf) for asylum seekers: "The Home Office are keen to minimise disruption to your life", and "The Home Office is the lead UK government department for immigration and visas".

Comment: US readers often ask on here about the 'odd' UK usage.